# How to block a page in Navigatior if it is already open?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am just starting to learn flutter, faced a small problem and hope for help.

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomePage.routeName)
```

I have 3 pages: A, B and C. All of these pages are available in the Drawer dropdown menu.
But if I am on page B, open my menu and select the same page again, it re-opens on top of the old page B.

I don't like this behavior and I would like to block the ability to open the page if it is active. How can I do it?

Comment: Now you can upvote if the answer is helped :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64413354/10659482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for this. You can identify a `currentPage` variable and check it before the navigation like this:

```
  onTap: currentPage == HomePage.routeName 
         ? null 
         : () { 
           currentPage == HomePage.routeName; 
           Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, HomePage.routeName);
         }
```